# Sort locations by latitude and longitude in database query

Tags: java, mongodb, latitude-longitude

1. In database (mongodb) are stored objects which have `latitude and longitude`.
2. For example I have point with `latitude and longitude` on server (tomcat).

I want to make `query` which will return me all objects sorted by distance from this point (from nearest to farthest),  according to their `latitude and longitude`.

Can someone help me, how to make such query? Just I don't know rules how to sort by distance when I have only `latitude and longitude`.

object structure in db:`{"id","name","latitude","longitude"}`

Answer (score 0):

From mongo DB help page - you can use $near 
All result are sorted from nearest one to the farest one from required point

> [MongoDB near help](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)
>          ...

syntax:

```
{
  $near: {
     $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
     },
     $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
     $minDistance: <distance in meters>
  }
}
```

> and usable example

```
db.places.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: Ok, thankyou, just not sure how to use it when I have two seperate fields for latitude and longitude. any help?

Comment: so in my opinion you should change data structure to have a GeoJSON type as this is native format for queering distance.  See more searching for  mongo point structure - if you need a help just give a shout :-)