# MongoDB sort document based on latitude and longitude

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I am trying to make a mongoDB query which **sorts the documents based on the latitude and longitude**. So nearest one will come first. I have below model structure for geolocation in mongoDB.

```
"place" : {
    "latitude" : "22.4856889",
    "longitude" : "70.0614146"
},
"address" : "Main Street",
...
...
```

So I have to sort based on latitude and longitude present **inside place object**. Any help will be appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: Can't you just consider latitude and longitude as numbers and do `$sort`. Is there any special case I am overlooking ?

Comment: If you are looking at sorting by distance from a particular point you can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688915/3659361)

Comment: I am looking from particular point. The answer that you tagged is with different model structure. Can you help with mine model structure?

Comment: Lemme run some queries locally and get back to you. My mongo is a little rusty rn

Comment: I had added new question. Can you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896501/mongoose-getting-error-noqueryexecutionplans-while-using-geojson

Answer (score 1):

In order to use near, the model structure should be like this ([GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#std-label-geojson-point)):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61224d9e52d4af7999de80af"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -73.88, 
            40.78
        ]
    },
    "name" : "La Guardia Airport",
    "address" : "Main Street"
}
```

And you have to create index in the collection:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

Then, find the nearest document by geoNear (you can calculate the distance also):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [
          -73.98142,
          40.71782
        ]
      },
      key: "location",
      distanceField: "dist.calculated",
      query: {}
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thankyou. This will give nearest locations only or all the documents with nearest first?

Comment: This will give all the documents with nearest first, you can use `$limit` in the end of aggregate to get nearest only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test it once in my application and accept the answer.

Comment: I had added new question. Can you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896501/mongoose-getting-error-noqueryexecutionplans-while-using-geojson

Answer (score 0):

use $near operation automatically sort with nearest point
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Comment: Thanks but how to implement query according to my model structure?

Comment: could you change your data to {place:[22.22222,30.33333],address:"etc."} ?

Comment: Thankyou. I have to change it in order to make it work according to what I need

Comment: I had added new question. Can you please check it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896501/mongoose-getting-error-noqueryexecutionplans-while-using-geojson

Comment: Please check now

Comment: checked and answerd